# Is DB2 more reliable and stable compared to PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, db2

Always i was using MySQL or PostgreSQL for my projects such as Web/Desktop apps.
I had data loss few times and thanks to old backup i was always up and running.

But for a recent project for Airport, i have to use something which never ever can lose its data at-least not database until it has power in the circuit..

So i am thinking DB2 should be the best for such risk less missions? Any idea or hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget vendor support when you are considering HA - who do you trust to help you out 24/7 when the chips are down, and how much can you afford to pay for that comfort.

Comment: PostgreSQL is well known for it's reliability. If you lost some data, it's unlikely it's PostgreSQL fault. PostgreSQL and DB2 are on parr when it comes to reliability.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All of the platforms you have mentioned can run close to zero data loss configurations. All of them could be deployed in a configuration that will fail.

Platform choice is one part of the puzzle. It will be your implementation of the platform that determines whether or not your requirements are met.

- [MySQL Cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/)
- [Oracle RAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/clustering/overview/index.html)
- [PostgreSQL High Availability](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/high-availability.html)
- [SQL Server High Availability](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/mission-critical-operations/high-availability.aspx)

In reality, high availability and disaster recovery are a trade off between uptime, [Recovery Point Objective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_point_objective), [Recovery Time Objective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_time_objective) and cost.

Zero data loss and zero downtime is expensive, complicated to setup and complicated to maintain. There is no free lunch.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add that since the question was answered, Postgres-XC has been released.  It is basically an open source fork of Postgres which allows for Teradata-style clustering which offers both high availability and write extensibility.  I would expect this to be the preferred approach in very high-reliability, high throughput environments.